# Nifi: How to read access/secret key for AWSCredentialsProviderControlerService independent of environment

Tags: apache-nifi, secret-key, access-keys, aws-credentials

We are currently set path of properties file which contains secret/access key for Credentials File for AWSCredentialsProviderControlerService . Issue, is we are changing properties path for prod and non prod each time we run nifi workflow. trying to come up no change on Configuration on Credential File path, so that access/secret key would be read regardless of prod and non prod. Since credential file wont support Nifi Expresion language, trying to make use of ACCESS KEY/SECRET properties ${ENV:equalsIgnoreCase("prod"):ifElse(${ACESS_PROD},${ACESS_NONPROD})} Issue we are facing, we are not able to store these access key/secret keys to the registry. Hence unable to implement this change. Is there any way to read access/secret key regardless of environment in Nifi. Curently we are using 1 property file for non prod nifi and 2nd property file for prod properties. In this set up, manually need to changed to credential file path when switching from prod to non prod. Trying to seamlessly work without changing path of credential file. Is there any way to make this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0ua.png)

Answer (score 0):

The process that uses the AWSCredentialsProviderControlerService does not support param or variables, but the AWSCredentialsProviderControlerService "credential file" property supports "Parameters Context" as entries, make use of this for your solution.

**Example:**

Trigger something --> RouteOnAttribute --> If Prod (run executestreamcmd and change the Parameter Context Value to point to prod credfile) else if DEV(run executestreamcmd and change the Parameter Context Value to point to prod credfile) --> then run you AWS Processor.

You can use the toolkit client to edit the parameter context, or event nipyapi python module.  It will not be fast tohu.